# How to add inline styles to description of Rails link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) development, and would like to know how I can add inline styles to a `link_to` method like so:

```
= link_to "<b>menu<b> link", args, class: 'button'
```

I would like to make the word `menu` bold. How can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use a class to achieve that? For example, a class named "text-bold" and "font-weight: bold" attribute for that class, placing that near the "button" class... Won't it work?

Comment: @ilter because I just want to have `menu` in bold, not menu link

Comment: Posted you an answer. I strongly believe that inner texts shouldn't have their own classes inside html tags. You can leverage the option I explained on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `.html_safe` on the name string:

```
= link_to "<b>menu<b> link".html_safe, args, class: 'button'
```

This allows the tags to be rendered as HTML instead of being escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following :

```
<%= link_to(args, class: 'button') do %>
  <strong>menu</strong> link
<% end %>
```

Comment: how would that go in haml?

Answer (score 0):

As for your comment, I would suggest you to surround `menu` with `<span>` tag. And as you have a `button` class for the `menu link`, when you have something like this:

```
.button span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

= link_to "<span>menu<span> link", args, class: 'button'
```

Your "menu" will be bold.
Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It prints out the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think @drinchev's answer should be a better option. You don't need `html_safe`, in my opinion. Is it really a matter of haml version?

```
= link_to(args, class: 'button') do
  %strong menu
  link
```